# Is it possible to exit a C console application without threads at any time by pressing a key?

Tags: c, cmd, command-line-interface, exit

Let's suppose I'm in a `while (1)` loop calculating something, would it be possible to quit the whole application by pressing a certain key?

It's a C console application without threads.

I'm pretty sure it's not possible, but I'm a newbie so hey. I can only imagine beeing forced to press a key by some function like `_getch()` or similar. But then you have to wait until the user presses the key and the calculation cannot run meanwhile.

Comment: In C, everything is possible ;P.

Comment: All tags are wrong - but - <ctrl-c> may do it (running linux)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I apologise for posing the question again, but it was not suggest when I posted it.

Comment: @defoe that's OK. Sometimes it can be hard to find the right search words.

Comment: Set up your program with an event loop and then use non-blocking input (and non-blocking calls in general). This way makes it so you don't need OS threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows systems, there's `kbhit()` function that is nonblocking and returns `true` when any key is pressed. So, you could change `while(1)` to `while(!kbhit())`, or you could `if(kbhit()) c = getch()` to read the char without waiting. But this is very crude solution, really..

Answer (score 1):

You could do that by using C "signals".

This is not really difficult to use. Take a look at this wikipedia page. ;)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_signal_handling